# emailIntent не работает корректно

Tags: java, android

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name) + ": " + getString(R.string.task_list) + " " + title);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///data/data/com.test.mytest/files/outTask.csv"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_email)));
```

В момент отправления письма показывается что файл прикреплен, а получатель не получает прикрепленный файл, в чем проблема подскажите пожалуйста

```
    String filename = "outTask.csv";
    String outText = getString(R.string.sendTasks_Nomer) + ";" + getString(R.string.sendTasks_Task) + ";" + getString(R.string.sendTasks_Time) + ";" + getString(R.string.sendTasks_Contact) + "\r\n" + text;
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
        // Записываем строку в кодировке Cp1251
        out.write(outText.getBytes("Cp1251"));
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

так я создаю файл и он автоматически сохраняется по пути "//data/data/com.test.mytest/files/outTask.csv"
и мне нужно этот файл отправить приложенным к письму, вроде в момент создания интента все работает корректно а дальше как уже писал получатель не получает его

Comment: Ну... Попробуйте разрешение в манифест на чтение файлов добавить...

Comment: а это как, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: и вообще можно так интенту путь к файлу передать или я чтот не так делаю?

Comment: Метки (теги) нужны для того, чтобы выделить основные моменты ВОПРОСА, по которым другие пользователи быстрее смогут найти решение аналогичной проблемы, а не для демонстрации собственных предпочтений в выборе IDE. Вопрос никак не связан с проблемами при работе IDE Android Studio и этот тег в вопросе не нужен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом

```
    final String DIR_SD = "FolderName";
    final String FILENAME_SD = "file.csv";

    String outText = "text in file";

    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "SD-карта не доступна: " + Environment.getExternalStorageState());
        return;
    }
    // получаем путь к SD
    File sdPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    // добавляем свой каталог к пути
    sdPath = new File(sdPath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + DIR_SD);
    // создаем каталог
    sdPath.mkdirs();
    // формируем объект File, который содержит путь к файлу
    File sdFile = new File(sdPath, FILENAME_SD);
    if (sdFile.exists()) {
        sdFile.delete();
        Log.d(TAG, "file.csv deleted");
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "file.csv not found");
    }
    try {
        // открываем поток для записи
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(sdFile));
        // пишем данные
        bw.write(outText);
        // закрываем поток
        bw.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "Файл записан на SD: " + sdFile.getAbsolutePath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name) + ": " + getString(R.string.task_list) + " " + title);
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(sdFile));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, getString(R.string.send_email)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17758686/3212712) из-за ограничений системы безопасности андроида у почтового приложения нет доступа к защищённому хранилищу вашего приложения. Оттого и файйл не отправляется.

**Решение:**

Поместите ваш файл в публичную папку на телефоне. Т.е. замените имя создаваемого файла вот на это:

```
String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "outTask.csv";
```

Отправляйте так:

```
ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
uris.add(Uri.fromFile(file));
emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```

Также надо добавить разрешение на чтение файлов: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20064021/3212712) и на их запись: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5819903/3212712)

Comment: путь на сохранение добавить другой?

Comment: если у почтового приложения нет доступа к защищённому хранилищу почему он в момент создания сообщения прикрепляет файл?

Comment: @java, да, надо переместить файл куда-нить в другое место. Почему прикрепляет?.. Ну, возможно отдаёт ваше приложение некую заглушку вместо файла. Чтоб почтовик не крашился.

Comment: а как поместить файл в папку самой программы, ведь в андроид после установки приложения создается папка приложения или я не правильно понимаю чтото?

Comment: В данный момент вы как раз и помещаете файл в собственную папку приложения.

Comment: String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "outTask.csv"; то что вы написали это в телефоне создастся файл или на флешкарте если она есть?

Comment: и где найти теперь этот файл после сохранения

Comment: сделал все как вы сказали, но все так вроде показывает что прикреплен, а после отправки нету файла у получателя

Comment: @java, согласно представленной вами информации вы всё делаете правильно. Я этим кодом файлы отправлял и всё приходило.

Comment: обязательно прописывать emailIntent.setType("text/html")?

Comment: а то что вы предоставили путь String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "outTask.csv"; это где хранится на устройстве как до файла добраться?

Comment: и может быть это в проблема в том что я тестирую на виртуальном устройстве?

Comment: @java, 1. у меня так работает `setType("text/html")` 2. путь выведите в логи и посмотрите... Он может быть разным на разных устройствах. 3. может быть.

Comment: File f = new File("/sdcard/download/outTask.csv"); это значит я на флешке создаю файл ведь так? если да то скажите как на самом устройстве в любом публичном месте создать файл пожалуйста, я запутался уже(((

Comment: Карта памяти публичное место. Если вы добавили разрешения в манифест, файл успешно записался, вы можете его открыть, и используете приведенный код то должно работать. Если вмё же не работает, то других идей у меня нет